# How to make images appear at their actual size?

Tags: graphics, pdftex

Whenever I insert an image into my PDFTex document (using the code below) it seems to be resized to fit the width of the page. I know I can change this using the scale parameter, but that means I have to play with the scaling factor until it comes out roughly the size I actually created it.

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{ikonos.png}
\end{center}
```

Is there a way to display an image without scaling it to the width of the page?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simply omit the optional argument and the picture will be inserted 'as is'

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics{ikonos}
\end{center}
```

Be warned, however, that `.png` files often don't include the correct information on resolution. This will lead pdfTeX to insert them as 72 dpi images, which may not be desirable. See other questions on apparently 'blocky' images, for example.

Answer (score 18):

Check the printing resolution of your PNG file. It's given in DPI, dots per inch. If necessary, adjust the resolution using a graphics software, there are free programs available. You might see that the DPI value of the PNG file affects the output.

You could use a pdfTeX parameter to specify the resolution of embedded images, if they don't contain that data: `\pdfimageresolution<integer`, like `\pdfimageresolution96`.

Alternatively, you may set the resolution by an option:

```
\includegraphics[resolution=300]{filename}
```

or

```
\setkeys{Gin}{resolution=72}
```

Comment: Where is the "resolution" kry defined? I get `! Package keyval Error: resolution undefined.`

Comment: The resolution key was removed recently. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392674

Answer (score 0):

If you insert the picture with scale=1, then the picture is at the size you created it. I don't really understand your problem. If you want the picture to appear more centered on the page, there is a solution with makebox \makebox[1\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[1.2\textwidth]{pic}}.

Other than that, you have to create your graphics according to the available text-area. I highly recommend that you export your graphics as vector graphics (pdf,eps). Scaling will then have no influence on the picture quality.

Comment: "If you insert the picture with scale=1, then the picture is at the size you created it."
Sadly, not always. I just tried embedding a screenshot from imagemagick in a latex document, it is upscaled and looks very ugly.