# Resize large images that exceed page margin whilst respecting existing scale

Tags: graphics, lyx, scaling

The solution posted here [Scale (resize) large images (graphics) that exceed page margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6073/scale-resize-large-images-graphics-that-exceed-page-margins) works great. Just to summarise, Dave Jarvis suggested

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Determine if the image is too wide for the page.
\makeatletter
\def\ScaleIfNeeded{%
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% Resize figures that are too wide for the page.
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
  \oldincludegraphics[width=\ScaleIfNeeded]{#2}
}
```

but unfortunately this breaks any scaling you apply in Lyx to an image. e.g. I have an image resized as so

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{nicecats}
```

My scaling of 0.5 gets removed by the macro suggested in the solution above.  I'm wondering if there is a way to have the macro apply any user specified scaling first and then check the width? Or perhaps check for any pre-specified scaling and if it exists do not resize. 
Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that it is unusual around here to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to have any greeting.

Comment: you do not need the `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` LyX does it already for you if it is in the user part of the preamble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use it this way, without the `\ScaleIfNeeded`

```
\newsavebox\IBox
\let\IncludeGraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
  \sbox\IBox{\IncludeGraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \ifdim\wd\IBox>\linewidth\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\usebox\IBox}\else\usebox\IBox\fi}
```

your parameters are first applied, then it is tested if greater than `\linewidth`

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to redefine `\includegraphics`. The default width can be set globally as described in the manual section 4.6 *Global setting of keys*:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% Determine if the image is too wide for the page.
\makeatletter
\def\ScaleIfNeeded{%
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\setkeys{Gin}{width=\ScaleIfNeeded}

\begin{document}


\begin{minipage}{2cm}
\includegraphics{smiley}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\includegraphics{smiley}
\end{minipage}

% Overwrite global width setting:
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{smiley}

% Overwrite global width setting: '!' = normal width
\includegraphics[scale=.2,width=!]{smiley}

\end{document}
```

This allows you to overwrite the default width setting if required.
Note that `scale` and `width` don't play nice together, so you have to decide on which one to use.

---

If you really want to mix `width` and `scale` you have to wrap the `\includegraphics` manually into a `\resizebox` (also provided from `graphics/x` package). Note the different `\ScaleIfNeeded` macro here which could be in-lined anyway because it is only used once.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% Determine if the image is too wide for the page.
\def\ScaleIfNeeded{%
  \ifdim\width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \width
  \fi
}

\let\origincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand*\includegraphics[2][]{%
    \resizebox{\ScaleIfNeeded}{!}{\origincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{2cm}
\includegraphics[scale=10]{smiley}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\includegraphics{smiley}
\end{minipage}

\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{smiley}

\includegraphics[scale=.2]{smiley}

\end{document}
```