# How to fit a large figure to page

Tags: graphics, scaling, calculations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best figure size adjustment when dealing with different image sizes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17380/best-figure-size-adjustment-when-dealing-with-different-image-sizes)

Given: a large figure, whose height:width ratio is unknown.
Todo:  Include this fig in LaTeX, such that:

- if the figure is very tall, then fit its height to page
- if the figure is very wide, then fit its width to page

How to do it?

Or in other words, is there way for LaTeX to get (or compare) the width and length of a figure?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Did you look at [Resize large images that exceed page margin whilst respecting existing scale](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12459/1952)?

Answer (score 143):

How about

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{myfig.png}
```

Comment: @lukmac: if you want the picture with the height equal to text height, remove width=\textwidth keyvalue and viceversa.

Comment: @ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Thanks for your answer. While this is relative common known, it is good to have it here for beginners to find. You should also mention that you need the `graphicx` package (not `graphics`) for this, even if it is standard package.

Comment: It's a nice solution but the caption goes over the page number when using \textheight

Comment: @xApple Just use something like `height=0.9\textheight `.

Comment: I am still looking for an adaptive solution to integrate the entire caption depending on its height. Since the text of the captions can change, it would be a good thing if the image size could be adjusted accordingly (automatically).

Comment: use `width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio` if you have multiple columns

Answer (score 23):

Given that the figure is large,  [the `adjustbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox) can be used scale the image to a specified maximum width and height and keep the aspect ratio:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand*{\MyIncludeGraphics}[2][]{%
\begin{adjustbox}{max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}}
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
\end{adjustbox}
}

\begin{document}
\MyIncludeGraphics{images/eiffel_tower}
\end{document}
```

As Martin pointed out, a simpler solution would be to use `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}]{images/eiffel_tower}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simply use `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and `\includegraphics[max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}]{<image>}`. Note that this will only scale it down if it is larger (as you assumed).

Comment: This is very useful also for cases where `\includegraphcs` is somehow involved, but not directly available for passing keyword arguments to it. This is the case with [SVG files exported to PDF for LaTeX using Inkscape](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf). In that case only the image width is adjustable through `\svgwidth`, whereas the height is not. So using an encapsulating environment like adjustbox seems to be the only solution.