# Add image to fit the whole page

Tags: graphics

How can I add those two pictures to my LaTeX document?

- To fit the whole page
- look like written by LaTeX

> [image: Image 1]
>
> [image: Image 2]

The code must represent the image in LaTeX, like that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[]{1.jpg}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: It would seem that pdflatex (which i assume you are using, you do not say) has mis-read the image size, which usually indicates a problem in the image. jpg is really better for photographs can you save (or convert) the page as png  or (much better) pdf?

Comment: i can convert them to png

Comment: if that is a page from a pdf file you can use `\includegraphics[page=4]{file.pdf}` (or the `pdfpages` package has more options)

Comment: even i use what told me still same problem not fit the whole page

Comment: If pdfpages package does not do what you need, edit the question to have a usable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101480/14757

Answer (score 7):

> To fit the whole page

Thi is the easy part. With the `geometry` package you can set an unnoticed margin and then fix the size the image to `\textwidth` (that now is almost the same that  `\paperwidth`)  and  `\textheight`  (~ `\paperheight`). This can produce some distortion if the image have not exactly the same height/width ratio that the paper (e.g. scanned images), but  you can obtain the best possible fitting simply adding  the `keeaspectratio` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.1pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{1.jpg}
\end{document}
```

Note that here is convenient use some like `margin=0.1pt` (or even -0.1pt) with `width=\textwidth` or  optionally  `margin=0pt`  with  `width=.99\textwidth` but avoid the perfect fit of `margin=0pt` plus `width=\textwidth` (then the image can jump to the next page).

For the next pages that must have some margin, you can use use `\newgeometry` to restore the margins.

> look like written by LaTeX

This is the hard part, since beside match **exactly** font style, font size and margins (not done in this answer, hard specially if the image is scaled in some extent) your second image also have a page numbers in right header and a lot of empty space.

Assuming that you want add LaTeX in the empty part of this this second page, this involve some others tricks.

One approach (left as exercise) could be put the whole image in the background  and left a empty box at the beginning of the page for the already filled part. Then change a  `empty` style header to one mimicking those showed in the second image.

Another could be a just use a top float, make a simple position adjustement and crop the image (not necessarily the source image):

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\geometry{margin=0cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,
height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{/home/fran/TR0OT.jpg}}
\newgeometry{margin=4.5cm}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}
\lhead{\thepage}
\begin{figure}[t]
\vspace{-4.5cm}\hspace{-4.5cm}
{\centering\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,
trim=0cm 40cm 0cm 0cm,clip]{/home/fran/ePIIa.jpg}}
\end{figure}

\section*{This is a LaTeX text} 

\lipsum[7-15]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've downloaded the images you've posted and they are in letter paper format.

If you want to include them in a a4 paper document you have to decide if you want to stretch them to fill the whole page or to have some blank space above and below them.

In the first case, you can use

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\pdfpagewidth,height=\pdfpageheight]{TR0OT.jpg}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
```

while, in the second case use

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\pdfpagewidth]{TR0OT.jpg}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
```

In the following example, I've added an `\fbox` to show that

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node at (current page.center) {\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\pdfpagewidth,height=\pdfpageheight]{TR0OT.jpg}}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node at (current page.center) {\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\pdfpagewidth]{TR0OT.jpg}}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage

My third page
\end{document}
```

And this is the result.

First page (with stretching)

[image]

Second page (without stretching, you can see the horizontal lines of the `\fbox`)

[image]

Another option is to use the `letterpaper` option instead of `a4paper` so the images fit perfectly in one page.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[scale=1]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\noindent\includegraphics{1.jpg}

\end{document}
```

another solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[a4paper,scale=1]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=1]{1.jpg}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what i really do is removing the margines of the document so it will fill the whole page enlse the types of papers are differente

Comment: Sorry the pdfpages solution may be not working with jpg but with pdf it does