# Largest image that doesn't get put on separate page?

Tags: graphics, floats

With an image in its own section of a document, like:

```
\subsubsection{Title}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{somefile.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

How can you set it to make the image as big as possible within the page constraints, but not so large that the image gets put on a different page to the title?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32886/how-to-fit-a-large-figure-to-page

Answer (score 2):

The following provides `\stretchtofitimage` which stretches the image vertically to fit on the "remainder of the page" by setting the `height` key-value using some calculations:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,graphicx,zref-savepos}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{geometry,graphicx,zref}
\makeatletter
% \zsaveposx is defined since 2011/12/05 v2.23 of zref-savepos
\@ifundefined{zsaveposy}{\let\zsaveposy\zsavepos}{}
\newcounter{stretchtofit}
\newcommand{\stretchtofitimage}[2][]{%
  \stepcounter{stretchtofit}% Next image
  \zsaveposy{fig:top\thestretchtofit}% Save vertical position on page
  \includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\zposy{fig:top\thestretchtofit}sp-\Gm@bmargin-1pt,#1]{#2}}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
Here is some text.

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
{\centering\stretchtofitimage[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}\par}

Here is some more text.
\end{document}
```

The calculation of the height uses [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s `savepos` module to store the vertical height (in `s`caled `p`oints) from the bottom of the page. Since this vertical height is measured from the bottom up, we subtract the bottom margin (provided by `geometry`'s `\Gm@bmargin`) as well as a `1pt` smidgen. There is some stretch allowed below sections, which this `1pt` removal accommodates for.

Note that the above assumes you are not using a `\caption` - it wasn't included in your code snippet, so this may be a fair assumption.

The image above includes a [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe), which is also supported by [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

---

If you want to have a single-page image with `\subsubsection` title, then you can get around without `zref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
Here is some text.

\subsubsection{A subsubsection\strut}
{\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\dimexpr\textheight-1.7ex-\baselineskip-1pt]{example-image-a}\par}

Here is some more text.
\end{document}
```

The measurements for calculating the `height` is based on the fact that a `\subsubsection` heading is set using `\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries` in the standard document classes (which has a regular `\baselineskip`) and a post-title skip of `1.5ex \@plus .2ex`. Again, the `1pt` difference is for good measure.

The `\strut` inside `\subsubsection` ensures proper usage of the `\baselineskip` for the title. You may not need it in your actual title.

Comment: Nice answer, but I think the idea was to maintain the aspect ratio as well (although the original question is admittedly ambiguous).

Comment: @SeanAllred: Yes, the intent of adding a `width` key is merely to show that the user can introduce other options.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly "hack" way of doing it, but the program generating the LaTeX can just be told the expected page size, and specify either 20cm high or 15cm wide depending on aspect ratio.