# How to prevent PNG and JPG files from oversizing for no reason?

Tags: floats, png

I am using Revtext 4.2 documents with 2 columns. I tried to add a picture by using the following line of code:

```
\begin{figure}[b]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{grad}
    \caption{Visualization of Gradient Descent}
    \label{fig:Gradient}
\end{figure}
```

This blew up the size of the picture and was about half a page big. Here is a picture of what it looked like:

[image]

I have try to use the solution presented in this thread [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32886/how-to-fit-a-large-figure-to-page)

And rewrote my code as such:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{grad}
    \caption{Visualization of Gradient Descent}
    \label{fig:Gradient}
\end{figure}
```

which only made it worse:
[image]

Full code with similar effect:

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint,
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
%\usepackage{hyperref}% add hypertext capabilities
%\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
%\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines

%\usepackage[showframe,%Uncomment any one of the following lines to test 
%%scale=0.7, marginratio={1:1, 2:3}, ignoreall,% default settings
%%text={7in,10in},centering,
%%margin=1.5in,
%%total={6.5in,8.75in}, top=1.2in, left=0.9in, includefoot,
%%height=10in,a5paper,hmargin={3cm,0.8in},
%]{geometry}

\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
\begin{document}

\date{\today}
\maketitle


\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{grad}
    \caption{Visualization of Gradient Descent}
    \label{fig:Gradient}
\end{figure}    

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{reference.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Definitely not "for no reason". `width=\textwidth` is making it as big as it needs to be to fill the page horizontally, and `height=\textheight` will make it as big as it needs to be to fill the page vertically.. If you don't want it that big, leave those out, or use `width=` something else, like `\columnwidth` maybe, or some fraction of `\textwidth` like `0.25\textwidth`.  You can also use `scale=` to set the size relative to the size of the original image instead. But it's *you* that's making it that big.

Comment: latex will not scale the images at all unless you specify that they be scaled. You do not need to prevent anything.