# xwatermark package: help using small caps and putting watermark on top of text

Tags: formatting, xwatermark, atbegshi

Hi in the linked question I asked how best to use `AtBegShi` to put titles on to of a page as a title. I'm using these as the equivalent of an `MS Word textbox` at the top of each page that carries the title of the document. [Using `AtBegShi` for labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98549/getting-atbegshi-to-start-on-first-page-and-reset-content-when-overwritten#comment212578_98549)

1. I can't figure out how to set the fontseries to `\bfseries\scshape` and
2. I can't figure out how to have the watermark print on top of the text rather than behind the graphic image that is the letterhead graphic.

Following @egregs comment below *what I want is*:

In the final document, the page is a corporate letterhead using `wallpaper` to set the graphic as the background and covers the first vertical inch of the page. The title will be overlaid on top of the graphic but offset in 0.35 inches and halfway down the graphic. I'm trying to produce the title in `\scshape\bfseries`. For the first five pages it will be title of the memo followed by a further five pages of specific titles underlying appendices.

The context is a slightly quixotic quest to use latex as my "daily driver production environment" in a corporate environment.

Any help appreciated

MWE that *doesn't work* and just hangs below. (`xwatermark` is hanging a lot for me, am I doing something wrong?)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\begin{document}
\newwatermark[pages=1-1,scale=0.6,fontseries=b,textcolor=red,xpos=0,ypos=0]{Rhubarb Rhubarb}

\put(0,0){custard custard\\custard custard}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that `xwatermark` is the right way; you seem to want a fixed header for your page and `fancyhdr` may be a better choice.

Comment: thanks @egreg. I'd looked at `fancyhdr` as an option but I need to have the header in a very specific place due to the size of the header graphic, and it isn't where fancyhdr would put it. I've been trying to use `textpos` with `atbegshi` and `eso-pic` with mixed results and `xwatermark` wih the problems above. Have I missed something and is this possible with `fancyhdr`? That would solve a lot of my problems. The only other consideration is that the title changes midway through the document to label appendices, but I think `fancyhdr` can manage that from what I recollect.

Comment: Can you add some more information about what you want?

Comment: What about `background` package? Also you have `tikz` with `remember picture` facility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution for what you describing is to use the `fancyhdr` package. Here is an example, where we place four ornaments at the corners of the page. (Can also be done with TikZ)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
\newcommand{\wbc}[3]{\vspace*{#1}\begin{center}
    \wb{#2}{#2}#3\end{center}\vspace*{#1}}

\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-36,5){\makebox(0,0)[br]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}A}}
    \end{picture}}
\rhead{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(29,5){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}B}}
    \end{picture}}
\lfoot{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-36,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}C}}
    \end{picture}}
\rfoot{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(29,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tl]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}D}}
    \end{picture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The command `\put` is from LaTeX's `picture` environment and helps to position the text or a picture. (TikZ will probably be a better choice, if you are going to draw anything fancy). In the example I just used a font with an ornamament.

Comment: Thanks @YiannisLazarides I used a simplified version of this, using the picture environment and the put but defining the font series on the fly and it did the job perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

*xwatermark* isn't the one "hanging" your run. You haven't loaded *xcolor* package and your `\put` is wrongly placed.

The key to get graphic watermark on top of text is `picture-on-top-text`. But in your case you need to use the star (`*`) form of `\newwatermark` to get all watermarks on top of your page text.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\newwatermark*[pages=1,textcolor=red,xpos=50,ypos=90,fontseries=b,
  fontfamily=put,fontsize=1.5cm,scale=1,picture-on-top-text
]{\fcolorbox{red}{blue}{xwatermark}}

\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

See more examples at [Watermark on pictures only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82180/watermark-on-pictures-only/82216#82216).

Here is Yiannis Lazarides' example with *xwatermark*. Using the key `pages`, you can select the pages that should receive the ornaments. Note also that, using `xpos` and `ypos` (as arguments of `\ornaments`), you can change the positions of the individual ornaments as you wish.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xwatermark,loops}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\ornaments#1{%
  \foreachfox[arg=##1/##2/##3]{#1}{%
    \newwatermark[coord-unit=cm,pages=1,color=red,xpos=##1,ypos=##2]{%
      \unitlength=1bp\relax
      \begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \put(0,0){\makebox(0,0){\fontsize{36bp}{36bp}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}##3}}%
      \end{picture}%
    }%
  }%
}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\ornaments{-8/11/A,6/11/B,-8/-9/C,6/-9/D}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that *xwatermark* often requires at least 2 runs.