# Resizing images based on DPI and display size

Tags: shell-escape

I find that my pdfs are exceedingly large, since I use many high quality pictures in them. To automatically reduce the quality, I found this question [ [Can pdflatex (or any tex package) automatically rescale included images which have been reduced in size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73444/can-pdflatex-or-any-tex-package-automatically-rescale-included-images-which-ha) ] with this really cool answer-code (thanks @daau):

```
% for downsampling large images: \includegraphicsRS
% (\includegraphics "resize")

\newcommand{\includegraphicsRS}{}

\ifnum\pdfshellescape=1
% Yes, enabled
% #2 is the filename - assumed relative
% IFP - image file path
% IFN - image filename only
% here resizing at 800 px wide
\newread\myinput
% must add default argument [] so typeout works
\renewcommand\includegraphicsRS[2][\@empty]{%
% run downsampling bash script
\immediate\write18{mkdir -p downsampled; IFP=#2 ; %
  echo "Processing $IFP" ; %
  IFN=$(basename $IFP) ; %
  echo "downsampled/$IFN" > tmpname ; %
  if [ ! -f downsampled/$IFN ]; then %
  echo "File downsampled/$IFN not found! Converting..." ; %
  % convert $IFP -resize 50\% downsampled/$IFN ; %
  convert $IFP -resize 800x downsampled/$IFN ; %
  else %
  echo "Found downsampled/$IFN - reusing." ; %
  fi ; %
} % end write18
% here we should have downsampled file
% retrieve downsample filename first
\immediate\openin\myinput=tmpname
% The group localizes the change to \endlinechar
\bgroup
  \endlinechar=-1
  \immediate\read\myinput to \localline
  % Since everything in the group is local, we have to explicitly make the
  % assignment global
  \global\let\myTmpFileName\localline
\egroup
\immediate\closein\myinput
% Clean up after ourselves
% \immediate\write18{rm -f -- tmpname}
% finally, include downsampled image
\includegraphics[#1]{\myTmpFileName}
} % end renewcommand
\else
% No, disabled
% in this case, \includegraphicsRS is just the usual \includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphicsRS[2][\@empty]{%
\includegraphics[#1]{#2}
}
\fi
```

Now I don't want to simply use a width of 800px for each image, but to calculate a width in pixel depending on the first parameter of `\includegraphicsRS` (e.g. `\includegraphicsRS[width=0.5\textwidth]{test.jpg}`).

For that I want to replace the string \textwidth with the actual textwidth in px.

**Q1:** I used

```
textwidth="\the\textwidth" ; %
TW=${textwidth:0:(-2)} ; %
```

inside the `\write18` environment. The first line works fine (returns something like '455.24411pt' for a4 with 2cm margins).

But the second line (intended to remove the pt at the end) does not work. Why?
I don't get it and can't find anything related.

**Q2:** Since it would require some more ugly steps (multiplying by something like 1.3, finding xx in `width=xx\textwidth` and calulating that) and the fact that after that it still does only work with `\textwidth`: Has anyone a better idea on how to do this?

Comment: I found at least how to prevent ImageMagick to produce larger files than the originals: -resize "800x\string>" does the trick.