# Use cleverref to display page range of included .pdf files

Tags: cross-referencing, pdfpages, cleveref

I have a document where I link to *numerous* external .pdf and image files. The person who uses this document needs to have a hard copy of all the linked documents and images. So, I would like to include all the linked files in the acutal document to make it easy to print but also to provide a page reference to the documents so that they can easliy be located.

In the MWE, I am manually including the linked documents at the end. However am running into a few problems:

- can't quite get the page ranges to be displaed via `cleverref`
- want to link to the first page and the last page of any included .pdf

[image]

### Notes:

- In my actual use case I will include the file name and a phycial page number on each page, but have not included that here so as to reduce the size of the MWE.
- The files I used can be obtained from https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ibn44ut007gwzyl/AADGxdzSXvNTiKC-AJ22NLF1a?dl=0 or you can use your own files as the problem is not specfic to these files.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6073/scale-resize-large-images-graphics-that-exceed-page-margins


\NewDocumentCommand{\AddLinkToFile}{%
    m% #1 = text to display 
    m% #2 = file to open upon clicking 
}{%
    \edef\ExpandedFileName{#2}%
    \IfFileExists{"#2"}{%
        \hspace*{1.0cm}File: \href{run:\ExpandedFileName}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}%
        \IfEndWith{#2}{.pdf}{% .pdf files has a page range
            \hfill\Cpagerefrange{#1 Start}{#1 End}%
        }{% non .pdf files are only a single page.
            \hfill\Cpageref{#1}%
        }%
    }{%
        \hspace*{1.0cm}File: \href{run:\ExpandedFileName}{\textcolor{orange}{#1}}%
        \typeout{**** Warning: Failed to link file "\ExpandedFileName".}%
    }%
}%


\begin{document}
\AddLinkToFile{Kant 1}{kant.pdf}

\AddLinkToFile{Eiffel 1}{../images/EiffelWide.jpg}

\AddLinkToFile{Lipsum 1}{lipsum.pdf}


\pagenumbering{gobble}
%% Now include the links files (eventually need to automate from here to end)

\newpage
\phantomsection\label{Kant 1 Start}%
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}, pages=1-last]{kant.pdf}
\phantomsection\label{Kant 1 End}%

%% If non .pdf we can have multiple images per page, so no \newpage here
\phantomsection\label{Eiffel 1}%
\includegraphics[max width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true]{../images/EiffelWide.jpg}


\newpage
\phantomsection\label{Lipsum 1 Start}%
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}, pages=1-last]{lipsum.pdf}
\phantomsection\label{Lipsum 1 End}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would separate the display text and the label name -- you will run into problems if the display text contains commands, umlauts etc.

Comment: Why don't you put a `\label` on the first and last page of each included PDF? At least putting one on the first page should be relatively straightforward, shouldn't it? I take it you want the number within the included document, that is, and not the original page number.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Good point. I plan to use an optional parameter to allow for those cases where I can't just use the text itself. Did not include that in the MWE as that is not related to my current issue.

Comment: @cfr: Yeah, that is exactly what I am trying to do, but am doing somethign wrong. :-( And yes, I want the page number corresponding to the new document, not the page number in the included pdf.

Comment: @PeterGrill It is horrible code ... does anything help at all?

Comment: It would be easier if you wanted complete PDFs included, of course, because then you could just count the pages. Then you could do it all with `cleveref`, though you'd still need a lot of labels. (But maybe `hyperref` provides an option for this in that case. Or maybe you could use that anyway. I don't know `hyperref` well enough to know.)

Comment: @cfr: I do include the complete pdf (via the use of `pages=1-last`). Won't have any case where I only include certain pages. I had just gotten everything working in my example (except for the reference to the last page of the included pdf) and was about to edit the posting. But, since you posted an answer, I will try to make sense of that first and it might solve my last issue (before the attempt to automte this).

Comment: In that case, you can avoiding falling back to the `pageslts` reference for the last page of the document, I think, because you can count the pages and then calculate the appropriate `pg:p<number>` using the page number of the first page and the number of pages. However, if you've solved it in some other way, I'm not sure how much use my answer is anyway. Do you want me to delete it?

Comment: @cfr: No, please don't delete it. I haven't yet digested it. I think I understand your comment about calculating the last page link. But, how do I determine how many pagesa are in the pdf. I don't see such  a macro in the `pdfpages` doc.  Hmmm, I guess I could use the `pagecommand` option to increment a counter for each page.

Comment: @PeterGrill Please see edit below. If you are using pdfTeX, you can eliminate my use of the counter in `pagecommand` and use `\pdfximage`. (This may work with e.g. LuaTeX, but I am not sure about this since many of the `\pdf...` things have disappeared in the current version.) However, I am not sure how to make it all work with `cleveref`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I now see you already discovered `\pdfximage` ...

Answer (score 2):

This is about as inelegant as you can possibly get, but maybe it will provide a useful suggestion somewhere along the line.

It does not use `cleveref` for the case in which a PDF is included at the very end of the document because I could not figure out how to get that to work. Instead, it uses standard `\pageref` for that case with a reference provided by `pageslts`.

For this to work, you assign a tag to each file which is used when adding the link and then when including the PDF. So a wrapper is used for `\includepdf`. On the positive side, this means you don't have to add the `pagecommand` explicitly. (You have to add a tag instead.)

```
\includelinkedpdf{<tag>}[<options>]{<file>}
```

includes the PDF and adds a great many labels. Note: it adds more labels than it adds pages. It also adds a label on the first page following the PDF, if there is one. (This is why there's a problem if the PDF is the last one in the document.)

```
\AddLinkToFile{<tag>}{<text>}{<file>}
```

adds the link. The link for the first page is straightforward. The link for the final page uses a set of labels placed on the pages of the included PDFs. Each one has a label of the form `pg:p<no>` starting with 1. The command takes the `<tag> End` reference and gets the standard page number for that reference, if any. If the page number is `0`, we assume this is the last thing in the document and use `pageslts`'s label. Otherwise, we subtract the page number for the reference `pg:p1`. We then set a counter to the result and use it to create a link to `pg:p<result>`. Which ... er ... seems to work ... possibly.

Note that `hyperref` wants to be loaded last with certain exceptions, notably `cleveref`. `pageslts` says to add `plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=true`, so I did that. `pageslts` will give an error if `\pagenumbering{}` isn't set, so I've added that to `\begin{document}`.

If you don't want page numbers to be displayed on the included PDFs, use `\pagestyle{empty}` in place of `\pagestyle{plain}`. If you use `\pagenumbering{gobble}`, compilation will fail with an error.

[image: links and things]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,pageslts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6073/scale-resize-large-images-graphics-that-exceed-page-margins
\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\AtBeginDocument{\pagenumbering{arabic}}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddLinkToFile}{%
  m% #1 = tag
  m% #2 = text to display
  m% #3 = file to open upon clicking
}{%
    \edef\ExpandedFileName{#2}%
    \IfFileExists{"#3"}{%
        \hspace*{1.0cm}File: \href{run:\ExpandedFileName}{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}%
        \IfEndWith{#3}{.pdf}{% .pdf files has a page range
            \hfill
            \edef\tempa{\hypergetpageref{#1 End}}%
            \ifnum\tempa=0 Pages \pageref{#1 Start} to \lastpageref{VeryLastPage}%
            \else
              \edef\tempb{\hypergetpageref{pg:p1}}%
              \setcounter{grill@pg}{\tempa}%
              \addtocounter{grill@pg}{-\tempb}%
              \Cpagerefrange{#1 Start}{pg:p\thegrill@pg}%
            \fi
        }{% non .pdf files are only a single page.
            \hfill\Cpageref{#1}%
        }%
    }{%
        \hspace*{1.0cm}File: \href{run:\ExpandedFileName}{\textcolor{orange}{#2}}%
        \typeout{**** Warning: Failed to link file "\ExpandedFileName".}%
    }%
}
\newcounter{grill@page}
\setcounter{grill@page}{0}
\newcounter{grill@pg}
\setcounter{grill@pg}{0}
\NewDocumentCommand\includelinkedpdf { m O {} m }{%
  \def\makefirststyle{\phantomsection\label{#1 Start}}%
  \def\makedynstyle{\makefirststyle\thispagestyle{plain}\stepcounter{grill@page}\phantomsection\label{pg:p\thegrill@page}\global\let\makefirststyle\relax}%
  \includepdf[
    pagecommand={\makedynstyle},
    #2,
  ]{#3}%
  \phantomsection\label{#1 End}%
  \clearpage
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\AddLinkToFile{kant}{Kant 1}{kant.pdf}

\AddLinkToFile{eiffel}{Eiffel 1}{example-image-a.png}

\AddLinkToFile{lipsum}{Lipsum 1}{lipsum.pdf}

\includelinkedpdf{kant}[pages=1-last]{kant}

\includegraphics[max width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true]{example-image-a}\label{eiffel}

\includelinkedpdf{lipsum}[pages=1-last]{lipsum}

\end{document}
```

## EDIT

In the above, the tags are simply used to create the labels at Start and End. If you're confident the filename is safe to use, you can obviously use that or make that a default with an optional override.

In the code below, I make specifying the tag optional in this way. For the PDF inclusion the optional argument is delimited by `()` because that macro already has a regular optional argument. Obviously this can be tweaked to suit.

The main point of this edit is to show how to do without the additional `\label`s on each page of included PDFs. The code assumes

1. that pdfTeX is used to compile;
2. that every page of each included PDF is used.

In this case, we can count the pages using `\pdfximage`. This avoids the need to create End labels. We can avoid the additional labels on each page by relying on the mechanism `hyperref` uses to enable indexing. This adds an anchor on each page which index entries access as `\hyperpage{}`. I'm not sure how to get this working with `cleveref`, but I don't know that package very well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6073/scale-resize-large-images-graphics-that-exceed-page-margins
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddLinkToFile}{%
  o% #1 = tag
  m% #2 = text to display
  m% #3 = file to open upon clicking
}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \edef\grill@tag{#1}%
  }{%
    \edef\grill@tag{#3}%
  }%
    \edef\ExpandedFileName{#2}%
    \IfFileExists{"#3"}{%
        \hspace*{1.0cm}File: \href{run:\ExpandedFileName}{\textcolor{blue}{#2}}%
        \IfEndWith{#3}{.pdf}{% .pdf files has a page range
          \pdfximage {#3}%
          \setcounter{grill@pg}{\the\pdflastximagepages}%
          \edef\tempa{\hypergetpageref{\grill@tag Start}}%
          \addtocounter{grill@pg}{\tempa-1}%
          \hfill
          Pages \pageref{\grill@tag Start} to \hyperpage{\thegrill@pg}
        }{% non .pdf files are only a single page.
            \hfill\Cpageref{\grill@tag}%
        }%
    }{%
        \hspace*{1.0cm}File: \href{run:\ExpandedFileName}{\textcolor{orange}{#2}}%
        \typeout{**** Warning: Failed to link file "\ExpandedFileName".}%
    }%
}
\newcounter{grill@pg}
\setcounter{grill@pg}{0}
\NewDocumentCommand\includelinkedpdf { d () O {} m }{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \edef\grill@tag{#1}%
  }{%
    \edef\grill@tag{#3.pdf}%
  }%
  \def\makefirststyle{\phantomsection\label{\grill@tag Start}}%
  \def\makedynstyle{\makefirststyle\thispagestyle{plain}\global\let\makefirststyle\relax}%
  \includepdf[
    pagecommand={\makedynstyle},
    #2,
  ]{#3}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\AddLinkToFile{Kant 1}{kant.pdf}

\AddLinkToFile{Eiffel 1}{example-image-a.png}

\AddLinkToFile{Lipsum 1}{lipsum.pdf}

\includelinkedpdf[pages=1-last]{kant}

\includegraphics[max width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true]{example-image-a}\label{example-image-a.png}

\includelinkedpdf[pages=1-last]{lipsum}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as before.

Comment: The tag could just be the file name (my file names do _not_ have any non-ascii characters in them).  Can you add some more explantion as to how the `\tag` is working?

Comment: @PeterGrill It is only being used to create the `#1 Start` and `#1 End` labels/references. I was just nervous about using the filename since it might include a path. (In my world, it might include a path, though it wouldn't include any strange characters in the filename itself.)

Comment: AFAIK, a path is fine as a label.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @cfr for suggesting that I determine the number of pages in the `.pdf`, I finally came up with a solution. This version labels each page of a `<file>.pdf` with

```
\label{<file>.pdf <n>}
```

where `<n>` is a counter that goes from 1 thru the number of pages in this `.pdf`.  In the page reference I [get the number of pages of an external PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198091/get-number-of-pages-of-external-pdf) and link to

```
\Cpagerefrange{<file>.pdf 1}{<file>.pdf \the\pdflastximagepages}
```

[image]

- Uses the `background` package to add page numbers in the bottom right margin, so that any page numberin in the included .pdf files is not altered.
- Handles caes where the same file is included more than once (useful when the second phase of this is automated)
- Provides special handling of `.pdf` files with a single page.
- My attempt to automate this is posted in [Expansion issue with automated solution using cleverref to display page range of included .pdf files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330170/expansion-issue-with-automated-soplution-using-cleverref-to-display-page-range-o).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6073/scale-resize-large-images-graphics-that-exceed-page-margins

\usepackage[all,nodeanchor={south east}, color=magenta, opacity=1]{background}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

%% Use background package to add actual page numbers in bottom right hand of margin
\newcommand{\FileName}{}
\SetBgContents{\tikz \node at (0,0) {Page \thepage\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{2.0em}\ttfamily\FileName}};}
\SetBgPosition{current page.south east}
\SetBgHshift{-0.5em}
\SetBgVshift{0.5ex}
\SetBgAngle{0.0}% Select rotation 
\SetBgScale{2.0}% Select scale factor

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddLinkToFile}{%
    m% #1 = text to display 
    m% #2 = file to open upon clicking 
}{%
    \edef\ExpandedFileName{#2}%
    \par
    \IfFileExists{"#2"}{%
        File: \href{run:\ExpandedFileName}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}%
        \IfEndWith{#2}{.pdf}{% .pdf files has a page range
            %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198091/get-number-of-pages-of-external-pdf
            \pdfximage{#2}% 
            \edef\LastPage{\the\pdflastximagepages}%
            \ifnum\LastPage=1
                \hfill\Cpageref{#2 1}% Only a single page in this .pdf
            \else
                %% Page range is page "1" to \LastPage of this .pdf
                \hfill\Cpagerefrange{#2 1}{#2 \LastPage}%
            \fi
        }{% non .pdf files are only a single page.
            \hfill\Cpageref{#2}%
        }%
    }{%
        File: \href{run:\ExpandedFileName}{\textcolor{orange}{#1}}%
        \typeout{**** Warning: Failed to link file "\ExpandedFileName".}%
    }%
}%

\newcounter{CurrentPageNumber}
\newcommand*{\LabeThisPage}[1]{%
    % #1 = label prefix 
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \stepcounter{CurrentPageNumber}%
    \phantomsection%
    \label{#1 \arabic{CurrentPageNumber}}%
}%

\newcommand*{\IncludePdfFile}[1]{%
    % #1 = .pdf file name (with path)
    \ifcsdef{#1 Previously Linked}{}{%
        \newpage%
        \setcounter{CurrentPageNumber}{0}%
        \def\FileName{File = #1}%
        \includepdf[pagecommand={\LabeThisPage{#1}}, pages=1-last]{#1}%
        \csdef{#1 Previously Linked}{}% No need to re-include this file
    }%
}%
\newcommand*{\IncludeImageFile}[1]{%
    % #1 = image file name (with path)  non .pdf)
    %% For non .pdf file we can place multiple images per page, so no \newpage here
    \phantomsection%
    \label{#1}%
    \def\FileName{File = #1}%
    \includegraphics[max width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true]{#1}%
}%



\begin{document}
\AddLinkToFile{Kant 1}{kant.pdf}
\AddLinkToFile{Lipsum Single Page}{lipsum1.pdf}
\AddLinkToFile{Eiffel 1}{../images/EiffelWide.jpg}
\AddLinkToFile{Lipsum 1}{lipsum.pdf}
\AddLinkToFile{Kant 1 Duplicate Link}{kant.pdf}
%% --------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Now include the linked files (eventually need to automate from here to end)
%%
\pagestyle{empty}
\IncludePdfFile{kant.pdf}%
\IncludePdfFile{lipsum1.pdf}%
\IncludeImageFile{../images/EiffelWide.jpg}%
\IncludePdfFile{lipsum.pdf}%
\IncludePdfFile{kant.pdf}%
\end{document}
```