# Scale figure if width < textwidth

Tags: graphics, floats

### Problem

I would like to automatically switch between `width=\textwidth` and `scale=1` arguments depending on the actual width of the image I am trying to insert in order to prevent it from being stretched if it is smaller than the text width.

### Edit / Solution

The following code is adapted from one of the proposed solution in this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6073/scale-resize-large-images-graphics-that-exceed-page-margins).

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\autoscale{
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width<\linewidth
    \Gin@nat@width
  \else
    \linewidth
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics % Resize small figures
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{
  \oldincludegraphics[width=\autoscale]{#2}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[]{img/test.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know this question has been asked before...just give a few minutes for someone to find the link.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Perhaps this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6073/scale-resize-large-images-graphics-that-exceed-page-margins.  With the `adjustbox` package, `\includegraphics[max width=\linewidth]{<image file name>}`

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes I had stumbled upon that thread but since it had it backward, I thought I would not delve into the seemingly complicated answers to try and reverse the process.

However, I did go back and ended up implementing the following solution:
    \makeatletter
    \def\autoscale{
      \ifdim\Gin@nat@width<\linewidth
        \Gin@nat@width
      \else
        \linewidth
      \fi
    }
    \makeatother
    \let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics % Resize small figures
    \renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{
      \oldincludegraphics[width=\autoscale]{#2}
    }