# Use scale if latex image is small enough, center in page otherwise

Tags: graphics, conditionals, width, ifthenelse, scale

I automatically generate a bunch of diagrams, and I'd like them to be automatically formatted to fit the page according to the following style:

1. If the diagram (in the form of a `.png` figure) is smaller than a certain linewidth factor `b=1.11\linewidth`, then I'd like it to have a fixed scale `a=0.5`, for example `scale=0.5`.
2. If the diagram is larger (at that scale of 0.5) than `1.11\linewidth`, I'd like the image to be scaled to have a maximum linewidth of `1.11\linewidth`.
3. If the image has `1.11\linewidth` I'd like it to be centered on the page.

The latter can be done using `\makebox` or `[adjustbox]` according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16584/161901):

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.11\linewidth]{latex/project6/Images/some_image.png}}%
  \caption{Some caption.}\label{fig:some_reference}
\end{figure}
```

My question is: how can I automatically detect whether the image width is larger than `1.11\linewidth` at `scale=0.5` (ideally parametrically) and automatically adjust the image width accordingly?

Comment: Hi! I do not understand that very well --- a `png` is a bitmap figure, so it's size is dependent on the density you want, i.e., it has no "natural" size. At 300dpi it is smaller than at 150dpi... Besides, maybe you just need `max width`? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32902/38080

Comment: Thank you for asking for clarification. The `.png` files that are generated have a fixed dpi and variable sizes, for example one image may have dimensions `300x123`, whereas another may have dimensions `200x2354`. So if the images in the pdf are below a certain linewidth, I would like to keep them at a fixed `scale=0.5` however, if that makes them to large for the page, I would like to limit their width to a `1.11\linewidth`. Thank you, I will look into `max width`!

Comment: Thank you, the solution was given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35731/161901). I voted to close this question as a duplicate.