# includegraphics image resolution stopped working

Tags: graphics, resolution, update, tlmgr

Using texlive 2016 and TeXstudio 2.12.6, the following example worked:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[resolution=300]{figure.png}
\end{document}
```

Then I did this:

```
tlmgr update --self
tlmgr update --all
```

Now, the same example gives the following error:

```
! Package keyval Error: resolution undefined.
```

How can I figure out what changed, and in which package(s)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The resolution key was amongst a rather large number that had 'appeared' in `pdftex.def` but were not supported in `graphics` and were undocumented. As part of the process of bringing `.def` support back 'in house' to the LaTeX team, these various keys were removed with *some* then being re-introduced in the `graphics` core (and documented). The `resolution` key is not currently supported: the team would need to see good reasons for adding this to the main body of `graphics`.

Comment: One good reason would be that (apart from using a pdftex primitive) there is no way to override the image's resolution without explicitly setting the width. This is a problem if your images contain text which should look the same as the text in the document (i.e. the exact same size).

Comment: @rudolfbyker in what way is specifying a resolution any different from specifying a scale factor (of the ratio of the default and specified resolution)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did some tests, and it seems that the density value embedded in the PNG file is ignored. In that case, scale and density are the same. I assumed that the scale is applied after adapting to the the PNG's density, and "resolution" overwrites it. Not so, it seems. If you take two pictures with the same amount of pixels in the x and y directions, but different densities, they still look the same in this example: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\begin{document}\includegraphics[scale=0.24]{figure_72dpi.png}\includegraphics[scale=0.24]{figure_300dpi.png}\end{document}`

Comment: I was using this in a command to detect low-resolution images and display it in a smaller size with beamer, but I'm not sure if this realy worked: `\settowidth{\imagewidth}{\includegraphics[resolution=150]{#1}}` and later `\ifdim\imagewidth>500pt` then use special command for low-res images.